# Passing mixed data type array from php to javascript array

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, json, getjson

This is close to the typical asyncronous / getJSON topics. I can't seem to get mine to work... I am loading an array from mySQL database in a php file "loadblocks.php" and have tested its output to work just fine by running the page and doing an echo json_encode($content);. All the data prints to the browser 100% perfect. However, when I am calling the json data in Javascript... the page is just not responding once I click the link with my onclick event.

```
<?php               
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","password","swim");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM blocks");    
$content = array();     // initialize block viewer array    

if($result){
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $content[$row["id"]] = $row;        // "id" is primary key id's
    }
}
echo json_encode($content);  // return array (validated)

mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Then I have the following in my HTML file... I need to load this multi-dimensional array of "block" data from the mySQL database. Essentially I need to do this when opening this "block viewer" html/javascript page and read all the data from the php variable "$content" into a literal "block" for each row in the multi-dimensional array. Each row contains a sort of educational curriculum requirement, a photo link, etc. etc... My HTML/jscript is as follows:

```
<html>

<head>
<script>
    function loadblocks() {
      $("#selectable").selectable({
        disabled: true
      }); // disable selectable while re-loading blocks in "selectable" viewer
      $.getJSON('loadblocks.php', data, function(jsonarray) {
        // store jsonarray once it is loaded in here
        blockarray = jsonarray;
        // in MySQL each row = (id, blocktype, title, description, imgurl, img2url, img3url, vidurl, goal1, goal2, goal3)
        // Thus index #3 in each row is the "title" we will load in each box for now
        // todo - create loop to load all rows
        document.getElementById("selectable").innerHTML += "<li class='ui-state-default'>" + blockarray[0][3] + "</li>";
      })
      $(".selectable").selectable({disabled: false}); // re-enable
    }
  </script>
</head>

<body>

  <table class="floatboxstyle" style="width:675px; height:225px;">
    <tr>
      <td>
        <ol id="selectable">
          <li class="ui-state-default">Sample block</li>
        </ol>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <button onclick="loadblocks()">Load Blocks</button>

  <br>

  <p id="feedback">
    <span>You've selected:</span>  <span id="select-result">none</span>
  </p>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You don't need to parse the JSON when you call getJson. It know's it's json and parses it accordingly.

Comment: Updated HTML code.... still not working though. This is more a rough draft of what my actual "block" viewing page will look like

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to use `parseJSON` for the response, `jsonData` should already be a JavaScript object, in fact that should probably be an error, although I usually use `JSON.parse` so I'm not sure if `parseJSON` blows up or not. I don't see you doing anything with `blockarray` in this code. And you don't have an error handler to report problems, try adding one.

> The success callback is passed the returned data, which is typically a JavaScript object or array as defined by the JSON structure and parsed using the $.parseJSON() method. It is also passed the text status of the response.[1]

[1] http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/

Also though you may be seeing the JSON print with the browser, it may not be valid JSON in which case it would fail silently.

> As of jQuery 1.4, if the JSON file contains a syntax error, the request will usually fail silently. Avoid frequent hand-editing of JSON data for this reason.

Try and validate your JSON to make sure it is actually valid, although I'd assume `json_encode` would do that for you.

Comment: I take it I should this "try / catch" error reporting function around my json line. Right now, even the above is causing the button press function to silently die... Will have to try this error handling later tonight. My full code is to pull user selected set of blocks (one column of this mySQL table has #1-5 options for block "sets" for an athletic training plan designer) and display the image url string in my its row in a list of options if the user selects that set of blocks. (eg: #1= biomechanics skills, #2 = physiological training methods, etc). Thanks so far!

Comment: That did not help out. No errors were returned using the try{} and catch{}

Comment: If you had errors, you wouldn't have needed a try catch, it would have just shown up. As the documentation says, the request fails silently if there's a JSON error. But I doubt it's a JSON error, I don't know what it is.